# variable not found / undefined after grunt build (uglify)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS for building a simple app with a map. As the main ctrl had too many logic I build a second controller for the navbar. Until here everything worked fine. Now I outsourced the map.on('zoomend' ... ) function when refactoring the main controller.

The problem now is, that when the navbar controller file is minified (through grunt build uglify) I get the following error:

> Cannot read on of undefined

That means, map is undefined even though it is declared at the top of the file AND I do not have the problem on localhost (grunt serve).

Navbar Ctrl:

```
'use strict';
angular.module('angularMapApp').controller('navbarController', navbarController);
navbarController.$inject = ['$scope', '$mdSidenav', 'helper', 'RespondService', 'shipTypes'];

function navbarController($scope, $mdSidenav, helper, RespondService, shipTypes) {
  var map = RespondService.getMap();
 map.on('zoomend', function() {
    timestamp = RespondService.getTimestamp();
    selectedShipTypes = RespondService.getSelectedShipTypes();
    selectedShipState = RespondService.getSelectedShipState();
    showGrid = RespondService.getShowGrid();
    helper.loadAndShowShipMarkers(timestamp, selectedShipTypes, selectedShipState, showGrid, map).then(function(results) {
      $scope.numberOfShips = results;
      RespondService.setNumberOfShips($scope.numberOfShips);
    });
  });
```

So this is a short version of my controller. The grunt file is still the same as created with yeoman. I too logged the map value at the top of the file, and there it has a value. However using 'map.on' might not work.

Maybe anyone can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your $inject seems to be correct, so minify should work fine for angular injection. It looks like var map is loading data from RespondService.getMap(). What do you expect to get from that function? You might want to put a break point and see if what you expecting is being returned.

Comment: I logged the result of var map, and at that point I have the expected value

Comment: what is the value? Does it have a function map()?

Comment: yes it's the same object as in the other controller. However var map is undefined when using 'grunt build'. We think the error might be somewhere in the init order of the navbar controller